# Was the villain of Superman IV based on a comic character?

Tags: dc, superman, superman-4

The Nuclear Man in the movie *Superman IV: The Quest for Peace* — was he a villain in Superman comics too?

Or did they create a new character just for the movie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Nuclear Man only appears in the movie *Superman IV: The Quest for Peace*, and the comic book adaptation of the movie by the same name.

However, he might be based somewhat on other characters from the *Superman* comics:

- In deleted scenes from the movie (scenes that were included in the comic adaptation), a "prototype" Nuclear Man is created by Lex Luthor first. This Nuclear Man looks a bit like [Bizarro](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Bizarro), and could possibly be inspired by that character.
- The superhero [Firestorm the Nuclear Man](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Ronald_Raymond_(New_Earth)) first appeared in [his own comic book](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Firestorm_Vol_1_1) in 1978, so he predates the movie and could possibly be an inspiration. However, he's a hero, not a villain, and doesn't really have a whole lot in common with the Nuclear Man from the movie, although some of their solar powered energy powers are similar to each other.

Answer (score 7):

There are only two appearances of Nuclear Man in Superman:

- Superman: The Quest for Peace - The Movie
- Superman: The Quest for Peace - The Comic

As the title suggests, the comic is based off the movie Superman IV: The Quest For Peace. It is adapted from the story by Christopher Reeve, Lawrence Konner & Mark Rosenthal and the screenplay by Lawrence Konner & Mark Rosenthal. However, the comic book adaption contains scenes that were ultimately cut from the motion picture due to budget constrants.

Answer (score 0):

Was just recently unveiled that Nuclear Man will be getting introduced into DC Comics. Brian Michael Bendis is writing a story with him in it for Superman #2.

Comment: Where was it unveiled?

Comment: This looks more like a comic than an answer; it doesn't directly address the question of whether Nuclear Man was based on an existing comic character (though there is an implicit "no").

Comment: @F1Krazy it seems to be suggesting the film character was the inspiration of a _new_ comic villain, if evidence can be provided of such, this is an answer. _"No, but it has inspired a new comic villain as seen here..."_